# Playframework action not catching some exceptions

Tags: java, playframework, exception, playframework-2.0

I'm rather new to Play and was able to implement an Action to handle PersistentExceptions on some requests. I am adding new exceptions to it and the problem is that they are not being caught and I cannot understand why.

I'm trying to move to a more functional coding also, using examples from play's github, and I got the following Error Handler:

```
public class ErrorHandler extends Action.Simple {

public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) {

    try {

        return delegate.call(ctx);

    } catch (NoResultException e) {

        logger.error("Error", e);

        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> notFound(new RecordNotFoundResponse(ctx.session().get("lang")).toJson()));

    } catch (PersistenceException e) {

        logger.error("Error", e);

        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> status(409, (new ConstraitsViolatedResponse(ctx.session().get("lang")).toJson())));

    }

    // Tried also to catch Exception with no success
    catch (UnexpectedException e) {

        logger.error("Internal server error", e);

        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> internalServerError(new InternalServerErrorResponse(ctx.session().get("lang")).toJson()));

    }
```

Controller:

```
@Authorization(userRoles = {UserAccount.ROLE_ADMIN})
@Audit(operation = ActivityLog.OPERATION_TYPE_DELETE, message = "Endpoint deleted")
public CompletionStage<Result> delete(Long id) {

    return EndpointOps.deleteEndpointById(id)
            .thenApplyAsync(aLong -> ok(new SuccessResponse(session("lang")).toJson()), ec.current());

}
```

Database access:

```
public static CompletableFuture<Optional<Long>> deleteEndpointById(Long id) {

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        Optional<Endpoint> endpoint = Optional.ofNullable(Ebean.find(Endpoint.class, id));

        endpoint.orElseThrow(NoResultException::new);

        endpoint.ifPresent(Ebean::delete);

        return endpoint.map(Endpoint::getId);

    });

}
```

When I try to delete a non existent Endpoint and throw the NoResultException, it is never caught on my action and get this log file:

> 2018-02-01 14:58:37 +0000 - [ERROR] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
>
> ! @76o8h094n - Internal server error, for (DELETE) [/rest/v1/endpoints/20] ->
>
> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CompletionException: javax.persistence.NoResultException]